# Set QComboBox to disabled on form load based on feature attribute value

Tags: qgis, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to display a QGIS 3 custom form combobox (QComboxBox) as disabled/greyed-out **on initial form load** based on an attribute value. The custom form was created with Qt Designer 5.15.2.
I can successfully control enabling/disabing the combobox based on a checkbox toggle after the form has loaded.

**What I have tried**: adding the code below to the very bottom of my formOpen function:

```
    if (myAttribute == 0):
        # I have confirmed through print statements this code level is executed
        cbMyComboBox.setDisabled(True)
```

It seems something else must happen after the form is displayed that re-enables the combobox.

**What I would like**: the comboxbox displayed as disabled on initial form load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this by placing the QComboBox inside a QGroupBox, then toggling the enabled status of the groupbox.